# Is there a better way to do this than using Thread.sleep()?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that does some task in the background after certain interval of time, at regular intervals.

However I want control over when the thread should get killed off, here is how I have implemented it.

```
class Task extends Thread { 
  private boolean kill= false,repeat = false;
  public void kill() {
    kill = true;
  }
  public void repeat() {
    repeat = true;
  }
  public void run() {
    do {
      //wait until the required time has elapsed
      while(!isTimeElapsed() && !kill) {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
      if(!kill) {
      //time to work, do stuff
      }
    } while(repeat & !kill);
  }
}
```

The code works as I required, but Netbeans notifies me saying, "**Invoking Thread.sleep() in loop can cause performance problems**". But it does not suggest a better way to do what I want to do.

But, is there a better way to do what I want, i.e to make a thread wait for a fixed amount of time, but have the flexibility of killing the thread whenever I want to as well ?

Comment: I would recommend looking at `Timer` and `TimerTask` to see if that will accomplish what you are trying to do. There are many good sites explaining how they are used.

Comment: Side note: `repeat` and `kill` should probably be volatile.

Comment: @JeffWard Thanks. These classes are exactly what I need.

Comment: @assylias I always make that mistake. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: `repeat` and `kill` definitely should be `volatile`. I wouldn't worry about performance, unless there is a massive number of threads all sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a primitive example that demonstrates how they are used:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Greeter {
   private static class SayHello extends TimerTask {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         System.out.println("Hello");
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      Timer t = new Timer();
      int delay = 0;
      int period = 1000; // milliseconds
      t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SayHello(), delay, period);

      Thread.sleep(5000); // Do something

      t.cancel();
   }
}
```

Comment: You should use a ScheduledExecutorService. Timer only uses one thread so if a task is lengthy enough it could delay the next one.

Answer (score 2):

This will create an instance of your class and run it every 1 second.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask myTask = new MyTask();
timer.schedule(myTask,1000,1000);
```

MyTask needs to extend TimerTask instead of Thread.